# Сохранить комментарии django.views?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Есть вьюшечка с отображением поста и комментарием под ним. 
Как добавить сохранение комментариев после добавления и нажатия на кнопку?

```html
def valpost(request, slug = None):
 instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = slug)

 comment = Comment.objects.all()
 form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
 context = {
 "title": instance.title, 
 "instance" : instance,
 "comment_form": form,
 "comments" : comment,
 }
 template = 'post_detail.html'
 return render(request, template, context)
```

https://pp.userapi.com/c626326/v626326759/5797d/XrGKMl1UT8c.jpg

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Не вижу у Вас вызова метода сохранения сущности. `form.save`

Comment: def valpost(request, slug = None):
 instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug = slug)
 comment = Comment.objects.all()
 form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
 if form.is_valid():
  form.save()
 context = {
 "title": instance.title, 
 "instance" : instance,
 "comment_form": form,
 "comments" : comment,
 }
 template = 'post_detail.html'
 return render(request, template, context)

 получаю 
 Exception Value:  

'CommentForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: А вы импортировали форму в файле? `from myapp.forms import CommentForm`

Comment: Проблема уже решена, спасибо